# config location ruby and using rake for unit test

Tags: ruby, rake

Learning Ruby, my Ruby app directory structure follows the convention
with lib/ and test/

in my root directory I have a authentication config file, that I read from one of the classes in lib/. It is read as File.open('../myconf').

When testing with Rake, the file open doesn't work since the working directory is the root, not lib/ or test/.

In order to solve this, I have two questions:
is it possible, and should I specify rake working directory to test/ ? 
should I use different file discovery method? Although I prefer convention over config.

## lib/A.rb

```
class A 
def openFile
    if File.exists?('../auth.conf')
        f = File.open('../auth.conf','r')
...

    else
        at_exit { puts "Missing auth.conf file" }
        exit
    end
end
```

## test/testopenfile.rb

```
require_relative '../lib/A'
require 'test/unit'

class TestSetup < Test::Unit::TestCase

    def test_credentials

        a = A.new
        a.openFile #error
        ...
    end
end
```

Trying to invoke with Rake. I did setup a task to copy the auth.conf to the test directory, but turns out that the working dir is above test/.

```
> rake
cp auth.conf test/
/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby test/testsetup.rb
Missing auth.conf file
```

## Rakefile

```
task :default => [:copyauth,:test]

desc "Copy auth.conf to test dir"
        task :copyauth do
                sh "cp auth.conf test/"
        end

desc "Test"
        task :test do
                ruby "test/testsetup.rb"
        end
```

Comment: please add the code that fails + stack trace

Comment: thanks, have added a responce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably getting that error because you're running `rake` from the projects root directory, which means that the current working directory will be set to that directory. This probably means that the call to `File.open("../auth.conf")` will start looking one directory up from your current working directory.

Try specifying the absolute path to the config file, for example something like this:

```
class A 
  def open_file
    path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "auth.conf")
    if File.exists?(path)
      f = File.open(path,'r')
      # do stuff...
    else 
      at_exit { puts "Missing auth.conf file" }
    exit
  end
end
```

Btw, I took the liberty of changing `openFile` -> `open_file`, since that's more consistent with ruby coding conventions.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [File.expand_path](http://apidock.com/ruby/File/expand_path/class) method for that. You can evaluate `auth.conf` file location based on `__FILE__`(current file - `lib/a.rb` in your case) or `Rails.root` depending on what you need.

```
def open_file
  filename = File.expand_path("../auth.conf", __FILE__) # => 'lib/auth.conf'

  if File.exists?(filename)
    f = File.open(filename,'r')
    ...
  else
    at_exit { puts "Missing auth.conf file" }
    exit
  end
end
```